# How do I exclude a user with a specific criteria where every row has the criteria for that user id?

Tags: sql

So I have a list of users who every time they have a feature created, a new row with their ID will be created. I would like to exclude all users that have feature B enabled.

```
USER   FEATURE
100    A
100    B
200    A
200    C
200    D
```

I can't do `select USER from TABLE where FEATURE =! 'B'` because that will still show USER 100. Any other solution?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all users are in this table, you can use aggregation:

```
select user
from t
group by user
having sum(case when feature = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If users are actually in another table, I would suggest:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from user_features uf
                  where uf.user = u.user and uf.feature = 'B'
                 );
```

Comment: Users are in the same table but it's saying error, feature is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause

Comment: This works for me in MySql. What database engine are you using?

Comment: @PhilK . . . These are both standard SQL and should work in any database.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as (select user from table where feature ='B')
select user from table where user not in(select distinct user from cte);
```